# Require 'rubygems' in Guard fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, guard

I most certainly have RubyGems installed, but "guard" fails:

```
/usr/local/bin/guard:9:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/bin/guard:9
```

What can I do?

Comment: 1: Type `which ruby` - observe result. 2: Type `head /usr/local/bin/guard` - look at the first line. 3: Do the two (1 and 2) match?

Answer (score 0):

There was a known issue [1]. Try updating to Guard 0.4.2 which should solve the issue.

[1] https://github.com/guard/guard-test/issues/11